# Message queue msgsnd mtext field

Tags: linux, message-queue

When using msgsnd the structure mentioned in man page is

```
 struct mymsg {
     long mtype;    /* message type */
     char mtext[1]; /* body of message */
 };
```

But if you use it like

```
func(char *array, int sizeofarray)
{
     struct mymsg {
         long mtype;    /* message type */
         char *ptr; /* body of message */
     };

    msgq.mtype = 1;
    msgq.ptr = array;

    msgsnd(msqid, &msgq, sizeofarray, 0);
}
```

Assign ptr to some local array[200] (array could be got as a parameter in function), the message received on the other side is junk. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's junk because the structure you have specified is *not* of the form that `msgsnd` wants.  It expects the data to be copied to immediately follow the `mtype` value in memory, not be in an array somewhere else.

If you want to send an array of length 200, you need to do something like:

```
struct mymsg {
    long mtype;
    char mtext[200];
} foo;

foo.mtype = 1;
memcpy(foo.mtext, array, 200);

msgsnd(msqid, &foo, 200, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if this wasn't wrong for the reasons caf points out, let's say you did something like:

```
func(char *array)
{
     struct mymsg 
     {
         long mtype;    /* message type */
         char *ptr; /* body of message */
     };

    msgq.mtype = 1;
    msgq.ptr = array;

    msgsnd(msqid, &msgq, sizeof(ptr), 0);
}
```

If a different process is reading the queue, what would ptr mean to it?  What would it point to, if anything, in a different address space?

Comment: It is not sizeof(ptr) but size of original array. Anyways.. I already guessed the answer which caf replied. I just confirmed.

Comment: I know. You missed the point.  I trying to demonstrate something else.